# i want last element of my arraylist and want to put it at 1st place

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want my last element from my arraylist and i want to put it at 1st position of my arraylist and after that i want to remove my last element of an arraylist.

```
    public class Array {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {13,25,35,74,5,16,73,8};
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please Enter Value to Swipe:");
        int position = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        List<Integer> NewArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();  

        if(position > array.length){
            position = position % array.length;
        }
        for(int i = 0;i <= array.length-1;i++) {
            NewArray.add(array[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("  "+NewArray);

        for(int k = position;k <= position;k++) {

              NewArray.add(0,NewArray.get(NewArray.size()));   
              System.out.println("  "+NewArray);
              NewArray.remove(array.length);

        }
         System.out.println("  "+NewArray);
    }

}
```

Comment: i can able to remove my last element from my array list but unable to get the value of my last element of an arraylist.

Comment: The last element of a list is found at `size() - 1`, not at `size()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here  is how you can do this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);

list.set(0, list.get(list.size() - 1));
list.remove(list.size() - 1);

System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[3,2]
```